# How to integrate unity game in React native app without WebGL?

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I want to build a React Native App with a sub-feature of my Unity Game.

Is there any way of integrating Unity Game in RN without WebGL?

Or is there any way I can launch the Unity Game App from the RN App?

If the WebGL is the only option then, what  could be the speed of my TCG Game? How can I improve it?

Answer (score -1):

In Unity2018.3, they release a new function call **Tiny Mode**. 
It support you to build html5 projects with a very small file size and memory footprint. Maybe you can give it a try.

Official document:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.13/manual/intro-for-unity-developers.html